# Update in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Platform PostgreSQL 9.2

I am very new to PostgreSQL. I have this scenario, which I have been able to address in MSSQL, but the same approach does not work with Postgres.

I have this table

```
CREATE TABLE TEST(
ID INT,
Value1 INT,
Value2 INT
);

INSERT INTO TEST
VALUES
(1,10,0),
(2,20,0),
(3,50,0),
(4,100,0),
(5,500,0);
```

I need a running total in the column `Value2`, like so

```
UPDATE TEST
SET Value2 = T2.Value1-T1.Value1
FROM TEST T1
INNER JOIN TEST T2
ON T2.ID=T1.ID+1;

SELECT * FROM TEST;
```

While this works perfectly in MSSQL, it does not work in Postgres. The command executes successfully, but no rows get updated.

However, when I try this, I can see that the logic is correct

```
SELECT T2.ID,T2.Value1-T1.Value1
FROM TEST T1
INNER JOIN TEST T2
ON T2.ID=T1.ID+1;
```

What am I doing wrong here?

[**SQLFIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/96a90/4)

Comment: What result do you get?

Comment: The command executes successfully, but nothing gets updated. Check out the linked SQLFiddle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: unlike SQL Server you do ***not*** repeat the target table when you want to update based on a join. So your update *should* look something like this:

```
UPDATE TEST t1
  SET Value2 = T2.Value1-T1.Value1
FROM TEST T2
where T2.ID = T1.ID+1;
```

But this update, won't catch the last row (or the first one depending on how you join them)

But with Postgres this can be done using a window function, which is probably a bit faster (and - at least in my eyes - easier to read):

```
with summed as (
   select id, 
          sum(value1) over (order by id) as running_sum
   from test
)
update test 
  set value2 = running_sum
from summed
 where summed.id = test.id;
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/96a90/43

Answer (score 3):

Look at the documentation here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-update.html

```
UPDATE TEST AS T1
SET Value2 = T2.Value1-T1.Value1
FROM TEST T2
WHERE T2.ID=(T1.ID+1);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/96a90/40